# Tar is currently reading a 2GB file, and I deleted its only link. How do I stop it from running for an eternity?

Tags: files, tar, rm, file-descriptors

Some more information:

I was backing up a large directory with `tar`, only there were a couple of large files there that I didn't expect. This connection is over the network and very slow, so simply waiting it out is not an option.

None of these files have anything important in them.

I erased the content of the first few with the `echo > file`, which preserved the link so tar would stop reading them, but then I and `rm -rf`'d an entire directory while `tar` was reading a 2GB file in that directory. Now, `tar` holds the only link to it, and I can't seem to find any way of making it move on it short of starting over completely.

The file is on an ext4 filesystem being accessed over the network by sshfs.

Comment: (NAA since I have no box here to check the details, but I think you can access that file through `/proc/(pid of tar)/fd/(number)` or somesuch, and _maybe_ you can truncate it with echo as you did with the others.)

Comment: You could probably trace tar with `gdb` or similar and force it to think it found EOF on that file... (Not posting as an answer because this requires a lot of explaining and some testing—anyone else who wants to is welcome to steal the idea for his/her answer.)

Comment: You could run gdb, attach to the tar process, get it to stop during a `read()` from the file, then give gdb the `return (int)-1` command to make tar think the read failed.

Comment: @Mark I think gdb has a way to break on functions.. This sounds like it could work.

Comment: I think it also provides a way to override the return value, so you could return `0`, signaling EOF.

Comment: @derobert's idea is better than mine. Return 0 from the read to make it look like it hit EOF.

Comment: @derobert Just gave that a shot with a test run of tar, got a `test.tar: Cannot write: No space left on device` error, after which it immediately died. `errno` was 0, so that's not the problem. Maybe `tar` was reading a different file... and that somehow caused the error? I guess this is the kind of shenanigans that happen when you mess with compiled binaries.

Comment: @Functino that sounds distinctly like you made the `write` fail instead of the `read`. Or messed something else up, which given is fairly easy if you're not sure exactly what you're doing.

Comment: @derobert: Nope, I've got the console right here and it says `break read`. It looks like there won't be an easy answer for this one, so I'm just going to kill `tar` and start over. :(

Comment: dont kill it. just check its fds. find the likely candidate. `echo >/proc/pid/fd/[num]` - like what you were doing before.

Comment: @mikeserv: Already killed. But if that works, you should post an answer. Someone else might need this someday.

Comment: i bet it would work. youd have to lead it a little, though. you'd basically need to dig a hole in the file a few bytes after `tar`'s current offset - `dd` would be ideal. `lsof` could tell you the offset, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`echo >file` would have been the straightforward solution. But once you've deleted the file, that's no longer possible.

But wait! Since you're using an ext4 filesystem, I presume that this tar is running on Linux. (Some but not all other Unix variants allow a similar solution.) On Linux, you can still access a deleted-but-open file via `/proc/PID/fd/FD` where `PID` is the process ID of the process that has the file open and `FD` is the file descriptor through which the file is open. This file is a symbolic link to the file, but it's a magic one. It remains valid even if the file is deleted. If you look at it with `ls -l`, you'll see something like

```
/proc/1234/fd/4 -> /path/to/file (deleted)
```

in all appearance a broken link, but you actually can open this file. In 
particular, you can truncate it with something like `: >/proc/1234/fd/4`.

If you're working on a system without `/proc`, you can use a debugger to cause the tar process itself to perform the truncation for you. Attach the debugger to the process, then make it execute `truncate(4)` where 4 is the file descriptor that tar is reading from. For example, with GDB, you can try something like

```
$ ps
…     find the PID of the tar process, e.g. 1234
$ lsof -p1234
…     find the file descriptor that you want to act on, e.g. 4
$ gdb -pid 1234
…
(gdb) call truncate(4)
(gdb) detach
```

This may or may not confuse tar as it could render some data structure that it's using inconsistent, so I recommend experimenting before trying it out for real.

Answer (score 1):

Stop the tar?

```
ps aux | grep tar

Find the pid of the tar process

kill $PID
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this means starting over a procedure that's already taken a long time. I'll probably wait another hour and if there really is no way to simply tell `tar` to "forget about this one," I'll bite the bullet.