# Remove Specific File From Tar Archival Process After the Process Starts

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, tar

When tar-ing up large directories (ie. a home folder for a backup/OS reinstall), it is often okay to exclude certain large files such as multi-GB videos. However, due to the all-encompassing nature of a home folder, it is often unrealistic to remember each and every file that may be useful to exclude (with --exclude) before starting. I am looking for some sort of input that I can give to tar to tell it to quit whatever file it's on and move onto the next, leaving the quitt-ed file out of the archive. Perhaps like a control-C, but instead of stopping the entire process, simply stop the current file.

Specifically, I am referring to a long running `tar -cvf` or `tar -cvzf`. As both of these commands contain `-v` it is easy to determine what file tar is currently on.

Using any sort of GUI tool is not an option, as tar is often run in a minimal (CLI only) environment on a broken system before a reinstall. This is the specific case I am asking about.

Comment: There is no `--exclude` in `tar`, you may have a vendor specific implementation in mind.

Comment: @schilly There is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984204/shell-command-to-tar-directory-excluding-certain-files-folders. Also, a screenshot of part of the man page: http://i.imgur.com/Y5tELkP.png

Comment: You are not talking about the man page for `tar` but rather the man page for `gtar`.

Comment: @schily The question specifies Ubuntu. On Ubuntu, `tar` is GNU tar and there is no gtar. Please stop confusing people by pretending that Unix variants other than your favorite one don't exist.

Comment: You might be able to do that with a variant of [the `gdb` usage in my answer to this related question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233128/tar-is-currently-reading-a-2gb-file-and-i-deleted-its-only-link-how-do-i-stop/233150#233150), with `close` or `lseek(fd, 0, 2)` instead of `truncate`. I'm not posting this as an answer because I'm not sure it would work, it may well crash tar.

Comment: @Gilles - Many people here do not know that Ubuntu comes with a vendor specific tar implementation and not mentioning that a vendor specific option (that does not exist elsewhere under that name) was used would confuse readers.  Please stop confusing people by trying to hide that fact from your favorite *nix variant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is possible, but you might simply just exclude large
files automatically from your tar. For example,

```
find mydir ! -type f -o \( -type f -size -1000k \) | tar cv --no-recursion -T - -f /tmp/tar
```

which does not save files bigger than 1000k.

---

Here's a script to ask interactively for a "n" reply to stop big files
being archived:

```
find mydir \( -type f -size +1000k -exec /tmp/biggie {} \; \) -o -print |
tar c --no-recursion -T - -f /tmp/tar
```

where `/tmp/biggie` is the script

```
#!/bin/bash
if ! read -t 10 -n 1 -p "$1 ok ?" reply || [ n != "$reply" ]
then echo >&2
     echo "$1"
else echo " ignoring $1" >&2
fi
```

which does a bash-specific read with timeout of 10 seconds of 1 char (-n),
with the filename as prompt (-p). If you type "n" within 10 seconds
the file is ignored.

Comment: There are some large files I want to save though. I want whatever program I am using to allow me to decide on a case-by-case basis without manually going through the entire directory structure. Perhaps it would be helpful to have it ask me for any files over 1G and then archive them if it doesn't get a response within 10 seconds (to allow for unattended backups).

Comment: I've added a script to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There is of course no way to tell a running program to change it's initial setup unless this program asks you for this.

If you just like to avoid large files, I recommend to use `star` instead of the non-standard tar you are already using.

`star -c -f out.tar -find startdir -size -1g`

Use the appropriate size instead of the 1G in the example.

This is much faster than using a separate find program call and this avoids side-effects from funny characters in filenames.

Comment: There are some large files I want to save though. I want whatever program I am using to allow me to decide on a case-by-case basis without manually going through the entire directory structure. Perhaps it would be helpful to have it ask me for any files over 1G and then archive them if it doesn't get a response within 10 seconds (to allow for unattended backups).

Comment: find allows to write even complex rules, so there should be a way to describe what you like.